# Best practice for distributing chef validation key

Tags: validation, amazon-s3, openssl, chef-infra, knife

I am using Enteprise Chef. There is just one validation key per organisation. That means that once I download it for my workstation, other devops people in team can't have it => they can't bootstrap nodes from workstation. If I automate process of bootstraping, for instance if I put the key on S3, then I also will have to think about keeping my workstation validation key and S3 key in sync (and all other devops people in team).

So question is:

What are the best practices for distributing this single validation key across nodes and workstations?

Answer (score 2):

My best bet on this:

- Use chef on your workstations to manage the distribution of the `validation.pem` file.
- Another way is to set it on a shared place (cifs or nfs share) for all your team.

According to [this blog post](https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/04/16/validatorless-bootstraps/) this will become unneeded with chef 12.2.

For the record, the validation key is only necessary for the node to register itself and create it's own `client.pem` file at first run, it should (must if you're security aware) be deleted from the node after this first run.

The [chef_client cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client) can take care of cleaning the validator key and will help manage nodes configuration.